# 1996 Subaru Not Starting

Tags: battery, starting, subaru, outback, legacy

My friend owns a 1996 Subaru Legacy Outback. I recently had to drive the car, but when I tried to start it it wouldn't start. When I removed the key a loud clicking sound came from somewhere behind the wheel. When I called my friend they told me that this happened all the time, I just had to unscrew and rescrew a screw on the battery (the green one in the top right of the attached picture). I did this and the car started.

I tried googleing this issue, but wasn't sure what to search for. Can anyone tell me what the problem might be, and if this is safe to drive?

[image]

Comment: Most of the time when stuff like this happens, I blame either the battery, or the connections to/from the battery. 90% of the time, this pans out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That green terminal thing looks like a battery terminal designed to provide an easy disconnect : when parking at an airport for a 2 week holiday for example.

It needs either removing, cleaning thoroughly and re-fitting or removing and replacing with a quality new one.

Comment: Thanks! This used to be a car that was only used in the summer, so that makes sense. We removed it and now the car starts fine. It looks like the screw was pretty corroded.